# Testing email system, spam injection tool recommendations?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, spam, testing

is there any free spam injection tools available on ubuntu for testing the email system ?

i would like to get free Spam inject tools for testing mail systems which i am part of development

**Edit 2** : Not going to test that in office network .. We are having private network for testing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do that when we were testing out some major tweaks to Spam Assassin. I ended up getting a throw away domain and making sure emails got plastered every where they possibly could.

Then, low and behold .. and endless supply of 100% USDA Grade A SPAM was delivered to our mail server.

The funny thing is, we shelved (parked) the domain for almost a year, found a need for it again .. the minute we pointed it at our mail servers the SPAM started again.

Now I use it to predict lottery numbers (though, it has yet to work). I gather entropy based on SPAM e-mails sent from the future :)